# won't connect to next activity android

Tags: android, android-activity

So I have an application and want to connect to activitys but for some reason it won't connect  and it crashes all the time

```
Thread logotimer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(1500);
                Intent logoLessius = new Intent("com.theludus.Mainpage");
                startActivity(logoLessius);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    logotimer.start();
```

this is the code that must connect the next page, and next is my android manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.theludus.Startup"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.theludus.Mainpage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_mainpage" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.theludus.NewGame"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_game" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.theludus.GamePage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_game_page" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

this is what my logcat says

```
05-12 15:22:05.393: E/AndroidRuntime(26537): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2649
05-12 15:22:05.393: E/AndroidRuntime(26537): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.Mainpage }
05-12 15:22:05.393: E/AndroidRuntime(26537):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1512)
05-12 15:22:05.393: E/AndroidRuntime(26537):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
05-12 15:22:05.393: E/AndroidRuntime(26537):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
05-12 15:22:05.393: E/AndroidRuntime(26537):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
05-12 15:22:05.393: E/AndroidRuntime(26537):    at com.theludus.Startup$1.run(Startup.java:21)
```

Comment: And what does the crash tell you in the Logcat?

Comment: i prefer to use this way to calling Activity

Intent logoLessius = new Intent(Startup.this,Mainpage.Class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
<activity
        android:name="com.theludus.Mainpage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_mainpage" >
</activity>
```

to

```
<activity
        android:name="com.theludus.Mainpage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_mainpage" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.theludus.Mainpage" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

When the activity is called with just a name , it is defined inside the intent-filter of activity. Otherwise activity can also be called with following method.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityName.class);
startActivity(intent);
```